# Join Vertical & Horizontal table in SQL Server using Pivot

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I want to join two tables and combine into one but problem is one table is in Horizontal Format and other in Vertical format.

below is the table structure and join will be on Employeeid:

Table 1 : EmpDetail

```
ID | CODE   | Name
-- |--------| ---
1  | 1008M  | ABC
2  | 1039E  | XYZ
3  | 1040E  | TYS
```

Table  2 : EmpCustomeDetail

```
EmpID | FiledName   | FieldValue 
--    |--------     |  ---
1     | FlD1        | temp1
1     | FlD2        | temp2
1     | FlD3        | temp3
2     | FlD1        | temp1
3     | FLD4        | temp6
```

Desired Output Required :

```
EmpID |  Code |  Name | Fld1  | Fld2  | Fld3  | Fld4 
--    |----   | ------|  ---  | ----  |----   |----  
1     | 1008M | ABC   | temp1 | temp2 | temp3 | null
2     | 1039E | XYZ   | temp1 | null  | null  | null
3     | 1040E | TYS   | null  | null  | null  | temp6
```

I had tried using Pivot Query but it is not giving exact output which i requried
Below is the query so far i have tried

```
SELECT A.*
FROM (
    SELECT
        e.Id,
        e.code,
        e.Fname,        
    FROM EmpDetail e  
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT *
        FROM (
            SELECT
                  d.CustomeFieldName
                , c.ComboValue
                , d.EmployeeId              
            FROM EmpCustomeDetail d
        ) src 
        PIVOT (
            MAX(FieldValue)          
        ) src2
    ) c ON e.Id = c.EmployeeId       

) A
```

Comment: Are all later column names (Fld1 to FldX) known in advance? Do you know their count?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are two statements:

The first is a simple `PIVOT`. You can use it, in case you know all Fieldnames (btw: there's a typo in your sample) in advance.

The second is roughly the same statement, but the column names are taken dynamically. This will work with (almost) any count and with different namings.

First a *mock-up*-test-scenraio

```
CREATE TABLE DummyEmpDetail (ID INT,CODE VARCHAR(10),Name VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO DummyEmpDetail VALUES
 (1,'1008M','ABC')
,(2,'1039E','XYZ')
,(3,'1040E','TYS');

CREATE TABLE DummyEmpCustomeDetail (EmpID INT,FiledName VARCHAR(100),FieldValue VARCHAR(100)); 
INSERT INTO DummyEmpCustomeDetail VALUES
 (1,'FlD1','temp1')
,(1,'FlD2','temp2')
,(1,'FlD3','temp3')
,(2,'FlD1','temp1')
,(3,'FLD4','temp6');
```

--The static PIVOT statement

```
SELECT p.EmpID
      ,p.Name
      ,p.CODE
      ,p.Fld1
      ,p.Fld2
      ,p.Fld3
      p,Fld4
FROM
(
    SELECT e.CODE,e.Name,ec.*
    FROM DummyEmpDetail AS e
    INNER JOIN DummyEmpCustomeDetail AS ec ON e.ID=ec.EmpID
) AS tbl
PIVOT
(
    MAX(FieldValue) FOR FiledName IN(Fld1,Fld2,Fld3,Fld4)
) AS p;
```

--The dynamic PIVOT statement

```
DECLARE @colNames VARCHAR(MAX)=
(
    STUFF
    (
        (
            SELECT DISTINCT ',' + QUOTENAME(FiledName) FROM DummyEmpCustomeDetail
            FOR XML PATH('')
        ),1,1,''
    )   
);
DECLARE @command VARCHAR(MAX)=
'SELECT p.EmpID
      ,p.Name
      ,p.CODE
      ,' + @colNames + 
' FROM
(
    SELECT e.CODE,e.Name,ec.*
    FROM DummyEmpDetail AS e
    INNER JOIN DummyEmpCustomeDetail AS ec ON e.ID=ec.EmpID
) AS tbl
PIVOT
(
    MAX(FieldValue) FOR FiledName IN(' + @colnames + ')
) AS p;';

EXEC (@command);
GO

DROP TABLE DummyEmpCustomeDetail;
DROP TABLE DummyEmpDetail;
```

Both lead to the same result...

Answer (score 1):

Try like below. If values of `fieldname` will not be static then you should use `dynamic sql`.

```
 SELECT EMPID,
           CODE,
           NAME,
           FLD1,
           FLD2,
           FLD3,
           FLD4
    FROM   EmpDetail C
           JOIN (SELECT A.*
                 FROM   EmpCustomeDetail
                        PIVOT ( MIN([FIELDVALUE])
                              FOR [FILEDNAME] IN([FLD1],
                                                 [FLD3],
                                                 [FLD2],
                                                 FLD4) )A)B
             ON C.ID = B.[EMPID]
```

Answer (score 1):

No need for sub-queries.

```
select  e.*,FlD1,FlD2,FlD3,FlD4 
from    EmpDetail e
        left join EmpCustomeDetail 
                      pivot (max(FieldValue) for FiledName in (FlD1,FlD2,FlD3,FlD4)) ecd
        on ecd.EmpID = e.ID
```

---

```
+----+-------+------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
| ID | CODE  | Name | FlD1  | FlD2  | FlD3  | FlD4  |
+----+-------+------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
| 1  | 1008M | ABC  | temp1 | temp2 | temp3 | NULL  |
+----+-------+------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
| 2  | 1039E | XYZ  | temp1 | NULL  | NULL  | NULL  |
+----+-------+------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
| 3  | 1040E | TYS  | NULL  | NULL  | NULL  | temp6 |
+----+-------+------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
```