# Create SQL Server table from XML data in specific format

Tags: xml, t-sql, sql-server-2012, xml-parsing, xquery

I have data stored in XML, which is structured in more of an HTML format than real XML. The element head contains column names and row elements contain data for these columns.

```
<root>
<head>
    <value>DeviceID</value>
    <value>VolumeName</value>
    <value>SizeGB</value>
    <value>FreeSpaceGB</value>
    <value>FreeSpacePercent</value>
</head>
<row>
    <value>C:</value>
    <value>c$OS-COMPUTER01</value>
    <value>126</value>
    <value>43</value>
    <value>34</value>
</row>
<row>
    <value>D:</value>
    <value>D$DB-COMPUTER01</value>
    <value>127</value>
    <value>104</value>
    <value>82</value>
</row>
<row>
    <value>E:</value>
    <value>E$COMPUTER01</value>
    <value>127</value>
    <value>106</value>
    <value>84</value>
</row>
</root>
```

The issue here is, this is just one of the collection items I have. There are other collection items, which have the same format, but possibly **different number of columns**, therefore I cannot just hard-code the column names into the select statement. Moreover some values can be empty.
Example of other collection item can be found below:

```
<data>
    <head>
        <value>FriendlyName</value>
        <value>DnsNameList</value>
        <value>NotAfter</value>
        <value>NotBefore</value>
        <value>Thumbprint</value>
        <value>Issuer</value>
    </head>
    <row>
        <value />
        <value />
        <value>08/23/2021 07:59:59</value>
        <value>08/23/2011 08:00:00</value>
        <value>E1A7D7E3BD6CA0C832182248EF7F092A72F9EB67</value>
        <value>CN=Hewlett-Packard Private Class 2 Certification Authority, O=Hewlett-Packard Company, C=US, OU=IT Infrastructure, O=hp.com</value>
    </row>
    <row>
        <value>Microsoft Root Certificate Authority</value>
        <value />
        <value>05/10/2021 07:28:13</value>
        <value>05/10/2001 07:19:22</value>
        <value>CDD4EEAE6000AC7F40C3802C171E30148030C072</value>
        <value>CN=Microsoft Root Certificate Authority, DC=microsoft, DC=com</value>
    </row>
    <row>
        <value>Thawte Timestamping CA</value>
        <value />
        <value>01/01/2021 07:59:59</value>
        <value>01/01/1997 08:00:00</value>
        <value>BE36A4562FB2EE05DBB3D32323ADF445084ED656</value>
        <value>CN=Thawte Timestamping CA, OU=Thawte Certification, O=Thawte, L=Durbanville, S=Western Cape, C=ZA</value>
    </row>
    <row>
        <value>Microsoft Root Authority</value>
        <value />
        <value>12/31/2020 15:00:00</value>
        <value>01/10/1997 15:00:00</value>
        <value>A43489159A520F0D93D032CCAF37E7FE20A8B419</value>
        <value>CN=Microsoft Root Authority, OU=Microsoft Corporation, OU=Copyright (c) 1997 Microsoft Corp.</value>
    </row>
</data>
```

I need be able to parse data with this structure into SQL table to be able to work with it in the future. The expected result would be SQL table, looking something like this:

```
DeviceID VolumeName      SizeGB FreeSpaceGB FreeSpacePercent
-------- --------------- ------ ----------- ----------------
C:       c$OS-COMPUTER01 126    43          34
D:       D$DB-COMPUTER01 127    104         82
E:       E$COMPUTER01    127    106         84
```

Currently I parse the head data and row data into temp tables and iterating over the respective tables building dynamic SQL code and then executing it to create another table and insert parsed data into it.

```
--code snippet which parses the rows
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) n, xx.value('.', 'VARCHAR(MAX)') v INTO #rows
FROM (values(@x)) t1(x)
CROSS APPLY x.nodes('//row/value') t2(xx)

...

--code snippet building the INSERT queries
WHILE (@loopcounter * @columns) < @rows
BEGIN
    DECLARE @insertstatement VARCHAR(MAX)
    SET @insertstatement = 'INSERT INTO #result VALUES ('
    DECLARE @forcounter INT = 1
    WHILE @forcounter <= @columns
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @rownumber int = (@loopcounter * @columns) + @forcounter
        SELECT @insertstatement += '''' + REPLACE(v, '''', '''''') + ''', ' FROM #rows WHERE n = @rownumber

        SET @forcounter += 1
    END     
    SET @insertstatement = SUBSTRING(@insertstatement, 1, LEN(@insertstatement) - 1)
    SET @insertstatement += ')'
    EXEC (@insertstatement)
    SET @loopcounter += 1   
END

...
```

I have searched this forum, but have not found solution, which would work dynamically with column names stored in such way. Could you please advise what can be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following query will retrieve all data in a non-pivoted format:

```
DECLARE @xml XML=
'<root>
<head>
    <value>DeviceID</value>
    <value>VolumeName</value>
    <value>SizeGB</value>
    <value>FreeSpaceGB</value>
    <value>FreeSpacePercent</value>
</head>
<row>
    <value>C:</value>
    <value>c$OS-COMPUTER01</value>
    <value>126</value>
    <value>43</value>
    <value>34</value>
</row>
<row>
    <value>D:</value>
    <value>D$DB-COMPUTER01</value>
    <value>127</value>
    <value>104</value>
    <value>82</value>
</row>
<row>
    <value>E:</value>
    <value>E$COMPUTER01</value>
    <value>127</value>
    <value>106</value>
    <value>84</value>
</row>
</root>';
```

--the query

```
WITH ColumnNames AS
(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS ColumnInx
          ,c.value(N'text()[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS ColumnName
    FROM @xml.nodes(N'/root/head/value') AS A(c) 
)
,TheRows AS
(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS RowInx
          ,r.query(N'value') AS TheValues
    FROM @xml.nodes(N'/root/row') AS B(r)
)
SELECT r.RowInx
      ,cn.ColumnInx
      ,cn.ColumnName
      ,r.TheValues.value(N'value[sql:column("ColumnInx")][1]','nvarchar(max)') AS row_value
FROM TheRows AS r
CROSS JOIN ColumnNames AS cn;
```

The result

```
+--------+-----------+------------------+-----------------+
| RowInx | ColumnInx | ColumnName       | row_value       |
+--------+-----------+------------------+-----------------+
| 1      | 1         | DeviceID         | C:              |
+--------+-----------+------------------+-----------------+
| 1      | 2         | VolumeName       | c$OS-COMPUTER01 |
+--------+-----------+------------------+-----------------+
| 1      | 3         | SizeGB           | 126             |
+--------+-----------+------------------+-----------------+
| 1      | 4         | FreeSpaceGB      | 43              |
+--------+-----------+------------------+-----------------+
| 1      | 5         | FreeSpacePercent | 34              |
+--------+-----------+------------------+-----------------+
| 2      | 1         | DeviceID         | D:              |
+--------+-----------+------------------+-----------------+
| 2      | 2         | VolumeName       | D$DB-COMPUTER01 |
+--------+-----------+------------------+-----------------+
| 2      | 3         | SizeGB           | 127             |
+--------+-----------+------------------+-----------------+
| 2      | 4         | FreeSpaceGB      | 104             |
+--------+-----------+------------------+-----------------+
| 2      | 5         | FreeSpacePercent | 82              |
+--------+-----------+------------------+-----------------+
| 3      | 1         | DeviceID         | E:              |
+--------+-----------+------------------+-----------------+
| 3      | 2         | VolumeName       | E$COMPUTER01    |
+--------+-----------+------------------+-----------------+
| 3      | 3         | SizeGB           | 127             |
+--------+-----------+------------------+-----------------+
| 3      | 4         | FreeSpaceGB      | 106             |
+--------+-----------+------------------+-----------------+
| 3      | 5         | FreeSpacePercent | 84              |
+--------+-----------+------------------+-----------------+
```

If you need your *table format* this is done with a dynamically created `PIVOT` command. [Here is one example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41257520/5089204) how to do that.

Comment: Hi Shnugo, thanks a lot! When I try this on more complex collection item - containing certificate data, it returns empty table. Example record: FriendlyName DnsNameList NotAfter NotBefore Thumbprint Issuer
Microsoft Root Certificate Authority 2010  06/24/2035 06:04:01 06/24/2010 05:57:24 3B1EFD3A66EA28B16697394703A72CA340A05BD5 CN=Microsoft Root Certificate Authority 2010, O=Microsoft Corporation, L=Redmond, S=Washington, C=US

Comment: @Mum, Please use the edit option to fill additional information into the question. Then place a comment to keep me alerted. And please avoid chameleon questions. If this is a new issue, rather close this and start a new question.

Comment: Thank you for the guidance. I have updated the original question with additional data example, on which your query returns empty table. I have also added short snippets of code demonstrating how I currently parse the data, which have the required functionality, but the code is kind of ugly not SQL-like at all. Additionally, I would like to return such dynamically created table as a result of a function - is there a way to achieve that in MS SQL?

Comment: OK, stupid me - during data processing the name of root element has changed. That is the reason for empty result. Sorry about that and thank you for your help!

Comment: @Mum You can change the `/root/head` to `//head` or to `/*/head`. The first will find a node `<head>` wherever it is, the second will find this node below one root node, however it is called. Do you need further help?

Comment: As far as the original question goes, everything is clear. Even though it probably should be new question, I will ask anyway: would you know how to display the table which is created by your code if the code is packaged inside of SQL function? Thank you.

Comment: @Mum If you really mean a **function** then no... A function does not allow for dynamically executed SQL which is the only chance to create a resultset with unknown columns. But you can use a *stored procedure*. Did you check the linked question for an example how to create a PIVOT statement dynamically?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165996/discussion-between-mum-and-shnugo).

Comment: @Mum please avoid follow-up questions... The strength of StackOverflow is by *one issue - one question*. This allows to search on this great site to find the answers for similar issues. So please start a new question for a new issue. If you want me to pop up there, please place a comment with `@Shnugo` here with a link. Anyway a new question has a much higher attraction and many knowing people will rush in for help.

Comment: Understood. Thank you for all your help and guidance.